# why is proc means displaying these f's?

Tags: sas

[image]

Not sure how to fix this I've tried to go into preferences but still hasn't fixed itself. Earlier it was displaying just fine, but I don't what I did to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can submit this statement to change the 'f' to something else:

```
OPTIONS FORMCHAR="|----|+|---+=|-/\<>*";
```

or on the `PROC MEANS` statement:

```
PROC MEANS DATA=... FORMCHAR="|----|+|---+=|-/\<>*";
```

This seems to be because your system does not have the 'SAS Monospace' font installed, as per the following webpage:

[SAS Community | FORMCHAR=](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/FORMCHAR_Option)